# How to validate signature with timestamp in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, timestamp, digital-signature

I have a signature which is signed  with outdated certificate
But this signature also inludes valid timestamp

How can I validate the signature using it's timestamp programmatically using C#?

Third party libruaries also are acceptable

Comment: Please provide more information/details. As it is now, it is hard to understand and answer your question.

Comment: In particular, please name or describe the validation model to use. Depending on that model the time stamp may or may not be of interest at all. The validation models you may use might be limited by the legal background in which the signature has been created and is to be used.